# What is the best practice to pass a Complex class instance to a REST Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am currently writing a java REST Web Service using Netbeans and Glassfish.
The WebService is a CRUD web service on an SQL database.
Netbeans did most of the work for me by implementing Simple CRUD methods.
But I still have 1 major concern: What is the best way to pass a complex object (like a date)?
for example: I want to write the function @GET getLessonsByDate(Date start,Date end).
From what I read, I can either use the @Consume annotation, @QueryParam annotation or @PathParam. What is best? what if need two dates? what if I also need another Complex data type?

please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services operate on strings. Ultimately all of your data is going to be formatted as a string, so you're better off doing the formatting yourself so you get control.

I would format your dates in a standard way, like YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS. As for other data types, it's really type-dependent, but JSON is often a good choice. The world is slowly moving away from XML as a serialization format toward JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I would use JAXB.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)

Here is a nice tutorial that should help you:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: +1 - JAXB is the default binding layer for JAX-RS.  Also since JAXB is a standard (JSR-222), there are multiple implementations available:  Metro, EclipseLink MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc.  Here is a link to a RESTful service example I have put together:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use json  to pass the parameters. 
 @Consumes("application/json") annotation enable to use the Json.